# Hive query fails in spark, but works in beeline Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, beeline

I am trying to create a hive table from spark using HiveContext as follows

```
hiveContext.sql("create table db1.table1 as select A.* from db1.table 2 A left join db2.table1 B on A.col1 = B.col1 and A.col2 = B.col2 where B.col9 = 1")
```

But i'm getting the following error message

```
17/07/19 10:27:25 INFO PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=OrcGetSplits from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl>
17/07/19 10:27:25 INFO deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
17/07/19 10:27:25 INFO OrcInputFormat: FooterCacheHitRatio: 0/0
17/07/19 10:27:25 INFO PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=OrcGetSplits start=1500452845775 end=1500452845815 duration=40 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl>
17/07/19 10:27:25 INFO PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=OrcGetSplits from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl>
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(col1#36#36,col2#37#37,200), None
+- Scan OrcRelation[col1#36,col2#37,col3#38,col4#39,col5#40,col6#41,col7#42,col8#43,col9#44,col10#45,col11#46] InputPaths: hdfs://path/to/hdfs

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange.doExecute(Exchange.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort.doExecute(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeOuterJoin.doExecute(SortMergeOuterJoin.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ConvertToSafe.doExecute(rowFormatConverters.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.doExecute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateTableAsSelect.run(CreateTableAsSelect.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
    at mcc.analytics.compute.jobs.Horeca_East$delayedInit$body.apply(Horeca_East.scala:75)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at mcc.analytics.compute.jobs.Horeca_East$.main(Horeca_East.scala:17)
    at mcc.analytics.compute.jobs.Horeca_East.main(Horeca_East.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1021)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$HadoopMapPartitionsWithSplitRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency.<init>(Dependency.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange.prepareShuffleDependency(Exchange.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(Exchange.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(Exchange.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:48)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$BISplitStrategy.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1010)
    ... 93 more
```

The same query works successfully in beeline. I'm not able to find out as to why does the query work as expected in hive but not through spark sql.
Can you let me know as to what is going wrong?

Comment: same problem, waiting for answers

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc to true :

```
hiveContext.sql("set spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=true")
```

It seems that the presence of 0 byte files causes this bug, and the above parameter helps Spark to use ORC files better ([source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19809)).